# VS2008 - Find and Replace - Searches too many files

Tags: visual-studio-2008, find, replace

I've used VS2008 a lot and have never had this problem. However, I started a new job and am using a new machine. Ever since I've gotten here the VS Find feature has been acting funny.

I first noticed it when I did a replace all for "All Open Files". The project wouldn't build because the values had actually been replaced in other files within the solution that were not open and didn't even open after I pressed replace all.

I have found that I can never use replace all on this machine because I never know what it is going to do. Even if I just do a find on "Current Document", once it's done with the document and I should get that message that says "No more matches found" it actually OPENS another random file from my solution where there is a match and keeps on going. It seems to never make any difference what "Look in" option I've chosen.

My coworker has an install off the same disk and claims to not be experiencing this. We're in the middle of a stressful, huge project with a close deadline so I know my boss won't let me do a reinstall.

Has anyone else ever had this happen? Anyone know a fix??

Thanks,
Pam

Answer (score 0):

ctrl+shift and click on F

Comment: Thanks for trying. Nut that just pulls up the Find in Files function which is a little bit different. Either way, Even when I did a Find in File with the "All Open Files" chosen, and only 6 files open, the results searched 36 files.

Comment: @Pam can you get by with using that find dialog, but setting "Look in" to "Entire Solution" and setting "Look at these file types" to `*.cs`?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. We have way too many .cs files and those are mainly the ones that are causing me grief anyways. (Trying to replace in only some .cs files but not all). Good idea though, thank you for trying! :)